# Add up values from matching fields in a linked Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I have 2 lists, say, `Fruits` & `Orders`.

- `Orders` has a number field `FruitID` that links to the `ID` field of `Fruits`.
- `Orders` also has a number field `OrderValue` which stores the value of the specific order.

I want to find out the total sale for a particular fruit. I am doing this calculation in a workflow for the specific fruit. Is there an easy way (read 'no coding')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the list of standard workflow actions here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx

There is no select, or looping functionality.

I suggest writing a custom workflow activity, sand boxing should work

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Sandboxed-workflow-activities-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks, djeeg. Do you have any pointers for Sharepoint 2007? That's what I am stuck with!

Comment: you can still write a custom workflow activity, but it will have to be a farm solution